Why can't I create a generic type that is restricted to only accept types with only string keys in Typescript?
I was reading the Typescript documentation and found this:
type Getters<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `get${Capitalize<string & Property>}`]: () => Type[Property]
};

And I wondered if there was any way to restrict Type in such a way that you could use Capitalize<Property> instead of Capitalize<string & Property>.
This is my best attempt so far:
type TypeWithOnlyStringKeys<Type> = {
    [Property in string & keyof Type]: Type[Property]
}

type TestingTypeWithOnlyStringKeys = TypeWithOnlyStringKeys<{
    helloWorld: any,
    44: any
}>;

// If you hover over `TestingTypeWithOnlyStringKeys` you'll see it doesn't have 44. Therefore it works.

type Getters<Type extends TypeWithOnlyStringKeys<Type>> = {
    // If Type extends TypeWithOnlyStringKeys<Type>, then Property should be string because Type has only strings as keys.
    // Why does it fail then? Am I asking too much to Typescript here? Is TS unable to properly deduce the type, or am I
    // doing something wrong?
    [Property in keyof Type as `get${Capitalize<Property>}`]: () => Type[Property]
};

It doesn't work because I get the following error:
Type 'Property' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'keyof Type' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2344)

Why does it fail though? TypeWithoutStringProperties<Type> does return a new Type that does not, in fact, have any non-string key.
Playground

In TypeScript, {a: string, 44: string} extends {a: string}.  So Type extends TypeWithOnlyStringKeys<Type> does not prohibit Type from having non-string keys at all.  keyof TypeWithOnlyStringKeys<Type> is a subtype of string, but keyof Type might be anything at all.  See this playground link for a demonstration. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
